# Load File in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new in TypeScript and Angular i would like to load an image from the local disk, store this image in a variable and pass this data to another component.

Someone has some examples. I tried using an example in Javascript, but it didn't work in TypeScrupt. In HTML file use this:

```
 <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

I tried using the image attribute, but got an error that is undefined.
Should I pass array bytes to another component or the path to this file image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, You can use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) directly from JavaScript even if you are using TypeScript.

On input change event, you can bind your component function to handle the event using `(change)`. The `event.target.files` is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileList) that allows you do directly access the files via an index ex: `files[0]` and send the File Object to the FileReader.

The issue here that a single FileReader object can only read one file at a time, so in the updated example, am looping over the files recursively to ensure only one file is being processed at a time.

The result attribute contains the data as a URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.

Here is an example component using Angular 2 - TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'images',
  template: `
    <input type="file" name="img" multiple (change)="onChange($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let fileUrl of base64Files">
      <img  [src]="fileUrl" />
    </div>

  `
})
export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit {
  public base64Files: string[] = [];
  private files: any[] = [];
  private fileReader = new FileReader();

  public onChange(event: Event) {
    let files = event.target['files'];
    if (event.target['files']) {
      console.log(event.target['files']);
      this.readFiles(event.target['files'], 0);
    }
  };

  private readFiles(files: any[], index: number) {
    let file = files[index];
    this.fileReader.onload = () => {
      this.base64Files.push(this.fileReader.result);
      if (files[index + 1]) {
        this.readFiles(files, index + 1);
      } else {
        console.log('loaded all files');
      }
    };
    this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

}
```

Comment: let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Is it a good idea to get the path to the file forwarding it to another component and displaying image there ? I read that I can get file object from FileList ovject.

Comment: Anas Al Hamdan example work fine fileReader.result string and how i may display this as image;                                                                                           let preview = document.querySelector('img');
        preview.src = fileReader.result;                                                                  How to display more than one file ?

Comment: I usually challenge new employees to do an Angualr application with similar functionality: 
Here are some examples that are solving a similar issue to your question:
1- https://github.com/belal-mazlom/angular-pix
2- https://github.com/malakalomari/task1-Image-gallery
3- https://github.com/montaserRahmani/angular2_clientside_images

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for a http request to a local resource.

Visit https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#heroes-and-http for an introduction.

Store the image to a service and you can inject that service into other components: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#creating-a-hero-service.